# Why is Styled Components Generating an Object?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have some very basic code that uses Styled Components:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Test = () => <div>foo</div>;
const StyledTest = styled(Test)`
  border: 10px solid red;
`;
console.log(typeof StyledTest); // object!!!
```

The problem is, that last `console.log` line logs `object` (NOT `function`), which of course causes an error when I try to use it.

This also happens when I try to style a component from a library:

```
import Modal from 'react-modal';
const StyledModal = styled(ReactModalAdapter)`
  border: 10px solid red;
`;
console.log(typeof StyledModal); // object!!!
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: While the answer here answers my question, for anyone running into the problem I ran into (ie. if you are getting an error about your `StyledTest`-equivalent not being a function/class), the answer is likely that your React/Styled Components versions are out of sync.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52973213/styled-component-rendering-triggers-element-type-error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `console.log` of a styled-component element, will always be an `object`.

For your code works correct you need to change the `StyledTest`, to:

```js
const StyledTest = styled.div`
  border: 10px solid red;
`;
```

and use this in `Test`:

```js
const Test = () => <StyledTest>foo</StyledTest>;
```

First you need to styling and after apply what you are creating.

To create like you did, the parameter you are passing in `StyledTest`, should be a style component, so if you have something like:

```js
const Test = styled(({ ...rest }) => <div {...rest} />)`
  border: 10px solid red;
`;

const StyledTest = styled(Test)`
  border: 10px solid blue;
`;
```

In that example, Test is a styled-component element, so you can edit this.

Comment: Thanks, it was the part about having to pass the props through that I missed ... they hide it in the documentation! ;)

Comment: No problem 
Yeah, it's always difficult to found everything on documentation.  
Sometimes I don't like documentations.